# Newtonsoft Json array deserialize or is this just a list

Tags: c#, json, json.net

On https://status.cloud.google.com/incidents.json Google is using a Json Array if I'm not mistaken. I am using Newtonsoft.Json and have deserialize the json using the code below. Am I using the right method to pull in the json?

```
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    String rawJSON = webClient.DownloadString("https://status.cloud.google.com/incidents.json");
    StatusCollection statusCollection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StatusCollection>(rawJSON);
    Console.WriteLine(statusCollection.Statuses.Count);
}
```

status.cs

```
namespace StatusJSONv1
{

    public class Status
    {
        string Begin { get; set; }
        string Created { get; set; }
        string End { get; set; }
        string External_desc { get; set; }
        string Modified { get; set; }
        MRUpdateContainer Most_recent_update { get; set; }
        int Number { get; set; }
        bool Public { get; set; }
        string Service_key { get; set; }
        string Service_name { get; set; }
        string Severity { get; set; }
        List<Update> Updates { get; set; }
        string Uri { get; set; }
    }


    public class MRUpdateContainer
    {
        string Created { get; set; }
        string Modified { get; set; }
        string Text { get; set; }
        string When { get; set; }
    }
    public class Update
    {
        string Created { get; set; }
        string Modified { get; set; }
        string Text { get; set; }
        string When { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Am I using the right method to pull in the json?` well have **you tried it out?** What is `statusCollection`, you are checking the count aren't you, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the JSON you linked to is a JSON array.  So you need to deserialize it into a list (or array).

```
List<Status> statusCollection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Status>>(rawJSON);
Console.WriteLine(statusCollection.Count);
```

There are a couple of other problems with your code however:

1. Your class properties all need to be `public`, otherwise Json.Net will not be able to access them.
2. The `Most_recent_update` property in your `Status` class does not match the name in the JSON (the JSON uses hyphens for this property).  To fix you need to use a `[JsonProperty]` attribute in your class like this:

   ```
   [JsonProperty("most-recent-update")]
   public MRUpdateContainer Most_recent_update { get; set; }
   ```

   You can use `[JsonProperty]` any time you want to use a different property name in your class versus what is in the JSON.

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8FtAJg

Comment: Glad I could help.